# Problem with creating external tables in SQL Server 2016 using Polybase

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sql-server-2016, polybase

An error is displayed when creating an external table. Can anyone tell me if this is a problem with the Hadoop settings in the core-site.xml or other file ? Is port 9000 correct for the settings on the SQL Server side, or should I use another ?

General architecture overview :

1. SQL Server and Hadoop run on other Windows Servers.
2. After Ping check, both servers can see each other.
3. In SQL Server, TCP transfer is set and firewall is set correctly.

**Error**

> Msg 105036, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
> External Data Source information could not be retrieved due to an internal error Exception of type 'JNI.JavaExceptionCheckException' was thrown.: Error [Call From xxxxxxxxxxxx/00.000.000.000 to xxxxxx.xx.dev.net:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:  >http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused] occurred while accessing external file..

**Hadoop core-site.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
            <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name> 
            <value>false</value> 
    </property> 
</configuration>
```

**Settings for an external source in SQL Server.**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyHadoop
WITH
  (  LOCATION = 'hdfs://00.000.000.000:9000' 
    ,RESOURCE_MANAGER_LOCATION = '00.000.000.000:9000'
    ,TYPE = HADOOP
  ) ;
```

**File Format in SQL Server.**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT csvformat 
WITH ( 
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT, 
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR =';') 
);
```

**External table in SQL Server (there is an error after running this code)**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [EX_SQLPolybase]
(
    id [int],
    [Name] varchar(50)
   )
WITH 
(
     DATA_SOURCE = [MyHadoop]
    ,LOCATION = N'[Test].dbo.Test_tbl'
    ,FILE_FORMAT = csvformat 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to start from the beginning, there are multiple things that need to be revised:

1. Check Polybase configuration and security for Hadoop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configuration
2. Make sure there is no blocking with the communication, you can use powercat as follows: powercat -c 00.000.000.000 -p 8020 -t 1 -Verbose -d
3. Have you configured 'hadoop connectivity' server parameter?
4. Have you restarted SQL Server services after modifying HDFS-related files?
5. Have you created master key encryption in SQL Server?
6. Have you tried creating the external data source without specifying the resource manager location?
7. The external table specification is wrong, LOCATION is a Unix path in HDFS similar to: LOCATION='/user/pdw_user/input'
8. Have you created in Linux the user "pdw_user" with access to the "location" path?

Detailed explanation and additional information can be found here: https://bpbonline.com/products/hands-on-data-virtualization-with-polybase